# Swift equivalent for returning nil from collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: (in case of failed assertion)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift2, throw, assertion

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource` also by defining the following method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
                             -> UICollectionViewCell {
     // ...
}
```

Inside that method there is an assertion that fails if execution reaches the default branch of a `switch` statement. Since this is in the context of a method, an arbitrary return value is needed: `nil` is my preferred choice.

```
switch ... {
// ...
default:
    assertionFailure(); return nil
}
```

This would work in Objective-C but raises a compile-time error in Swift, because the contract defines a non-optional return type.

> Nil is incompatible with return type 'UICollectionViewCell'

What is a best practice for handling this situation? I don't want to register/dequeue a special cell type just to satisfy the compiler. Can I somehow get by without returning any value from the default branch, or can I throw an appropriate exception instead (and if so, how)?

Comment: If you're switching on an enum I believe the compiler is smart enough to qualify each case without a default. Otherwise you can return just a default UICollectionViewCell() since it will probably never been executed anyway.

Comment: @thefredelement I am not switching on an enum but on a near equivalent of  `indexPath.section % 2`.

Comment: I do almost exactly that with a tableView in an app and return a UITableViewCell()

Comment: @thefredelement Perfect. (I did not notice the default constructor). If you want to turn your last comment into an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: @Drux, the only way to handle your case is to return a UITableViewCell()  as  thefredelement said.

Comment: If you call `fatalError()` instead of `assertionFailure()` then you don't have to return a dummy cell.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, `fatalError()` (and `@noreturn`) appear even better.

Comment: Nice @MartinR I think that's way better.